# OpenVPN Tunnel Through Tunnel

Tags: vpn, routing, openvpn, raspbian

I have a Raspberry Pi and two VPN server hosted.
In raspberry pi I installed OpenVPN. I did connect Pi with my 1st VPN server. My question is I like to connect 2nd server thought 1st server.

Like to mention that 1st server provides DHCP as like 192.168.5.101 and 2nd server also provide DHCP as like 192.168.6.101.

So how do I do this?
I able to initiate the connection with 1st Server but don't know how to connect 2nd one thought 2nd one. My goal is to make wifi hotspot when 2nd VPN connection up thought 1st VPN.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Push appropriate routes from the first VPN server such that connections to the second are routed through the tunnel.

Comment: What should I put in OpenVPN config??